# What will happen to SQLite Virtual Table when the android application is destroyed

Tags: android, sqlite

I was about to implement a search view to my android application and I've stumbled upon SQLite Virtual Table, and to me, it would be a best approach to do a full text search in my case. But, the word "virtual" causes me to think that a virtual table will be lost if the application is destroyed.

So my question is, will the virtual table be destroyed after the application exits or will it be stored just like a normal table?

Notes: I plan to link the virtual table to the external one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Virtal" just means that the table is not actually implemented by the SQLite core itself.

The FTS extension stores the table data in [shadow tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#shadow_tables), so an FTS table is as durable as 'normal' tables.

Comment: Thank you sir, for clarifying that for me.